# "An object with the same key already exists in the ObjectStateManager" on Entity.Attach

Tags: linq, entity-framework, c#-4.0

I am using Entity Framework Code first my classes are

```
[Serializable]
    public class Emp
    {
        public int EmpId { get; set; }
        public byte TitleId { get; set; }
        [MaxLength(50)]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        [MaxLength(50)]
        public string Surname { get; set; }
        public byte Type { get; set; }

        public List<PracticeEmp> PracticeEmps { get; set; }
    }

[Serializable]
    public class PracticeEmp
    {
        public int PracticeStaffId { get; set; }
        public int PracticeId { get; set; }
        public int EmpId { get; set; }
        public DateTime? StartDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime? EndDate { get; set; }

        public Emp Emp { get; set; }
    }
```

when I am trying to insert data into PracticeEmps table for a staff which already exists I use the following code

```
Db.Current.Emps.Attach(practiceEmp.Emp);
Db.Current.PracticeEmps.Add(practiceEmp);
```

This code segment returns an error on attach method "An object with the same key already exists in the ObjectStateManager. The ObjectStateManager cannot track multiple objects with the same key."

any Ideas...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

practiceEmp instance will be automatically attached to your context if the Emp instance you are attaching has a reference to it and it is not part of the context already. Note that both entities will be in Unchanged state which is the default state for attached entities.

Comment: If I remove Db.Current.Staffs.Attach(practiceEmp.Emp); Entity Framework inserts data into both table which result in duplication of data in Emp table.

Comment: Do you have any of these entities already database before adding/attaching them? You want to add both, attach both, add one and attach the other?

Comment: I want to insert into PracticeEmps table with a foreign key of Emps table.

Comment: For attach the assumption is that the entity in the database looks the same as the one you are attaching (this is the reason why entities after attaching are in Unchanged state). This does not seem the case here as you have a relationship that does not exist in the database. Can you try break the relationship. Attach and Add entities as you do now and update the relationship once entities are tracked?

Comment: I am a beginner level developer.. can you please elaborate break the relationship and update the relationship? with some example code..

Comment: Set the Emp property to null and remove the corresponding object from the PracticeEmps list so that there is no way to get from one entity to another

Comment: Thanks Pawel I have commented out the attach method and simply marked practiceEmp.Emp = null;
Db.Current.PracticeEmps.Add(practiceEmp); This did the job for me.